# Eliminating $x^2$ from a series of equations.

Tags: systems-of-equations, convex-optimization

I've stumbled across a bizarre problem, when doing some very basic calculations.

**The Context:**

Given two equations:

$\frac12x^2 +y - 4 = 0$

$3x^2 - 4x - 3y = 0$

The correct answer I want when I solve for is $x^2 - \frac89x - \frac83$

I can either do this by equating them both (via $y$), and then just simplifying, or setting one or the other to y, and substituting. (Essentially the same thing).

e.g. using the first equation: $y = 4 - \frac12x^2$

Then substituting into the second equation we get: $3x^2 -4x - 3(4 - \frac12x^2) = 0$
Which gives the desired  $x^2 - \frac89x - \frac83 = 0$

**The Issue**

When I first tried this, I actually equated the $x^2$ terms, cancelled them out, got $x$ in terms of $y$ and then substituted that equation into one of the original equations. You get completely the wrong answer e.g.multiplying the first equations by 6, and keeping the second you get.

$3x^2 +6y - 24 = 0$

$3x^2 - 4x - 3y = 0$

At this point if I eliminated y and solved it still works, but if I eliminate $x^2$ it goes wrong. You get $y = \frac{4(6+x)}9$

When you substitute this into either of the equations you get the wrong answer.

**What is going on?** I can't explain to myself why this is the case. I know effort here is important so I actually tried to visualise it all to help me understand (See link), but still stuck tbh: https://www.geogebra.org/calculator

*P.s. The wider context is that this calculation is part of a constrained optimisation problem, and this is one of the possible cases under the KKT conditions, I doubt this is needed but if so I will include.*

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: "You get $y = \frac{4(6+x)}9$". No, I get $9y=20x$.

Comment: Moo Appologies there is a typo - The equation should've been $3x^2 + 6y - 24$ not $24x$.

Thanks for replying though. Do you have any insight on the question? I have corrected the typo.

Comment: Thank you as well @Dietrich Burde I have corrected the typo (which started in the original equation). But the core problem still persists, any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have made a sign error. Subtracting $3 x^2 - 4 x - 3 y = 0$ from $3 x^2 + 6 y - 24 = 0$ gives
$4 x + 9 y - 24 = 0$, so $$ y = \frac{24 - 4 x}{9}$$
Substitute that for $y$ in the first equation and you get
$$ \frac{x^2}{2}  - \frac{4}{9} x - \frac{4}{3} = 0$$
which is equivalent to the desired $x^2 - \frac{8}{9} x - \frac{8}{3} = 0$.

Comment: Thank you Robert! The sign was a typo - but your answer made me realise what I was originally doing wrong. I was substituting $y = \frac{24 - 4 x}{9}$ into the original equation $\frac12x^2 +y - 4 = 0$, rather than the multiplied version $3 x^2 + 6 y - 24 = 0$. Thanks so much!

Is there any kind of basic example you can think of that illustrates why this wouldn't work. I.e. a mini proof, that shows there is a logical error, by substitution into the original equation?

Comment: Substituting correctly should give a correct answer.